# Performance of writing out repeating regex vs specifying number of sequences

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression like `\r?\n\r?\n`. I can write it as `(\r?\n){2}` using the exact same number of characters.

Is there any difference performance wise between the two? Or a best practices for this kind of situation.

Comment: Instead of asking and blindly accepting performance-related questions, you could simply use [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com) to find out yourself. You even have the option of running your tests in any browser you have installed and asking your friends to run the test on browsers you might not have.

Comment: JavaScript is outside my normal area of work and I had never heard of jsperf before. Definitely adding it to my bookmarks now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a JSPerf to show that using a repeating pattern is a lot faster than using `{2}`: http://jsperf.com/js-repeated-regexp-or-specific-number-of-sequences

Comment: That's a RAD site, I'm totally keeping that. It looks like they complete in a different order than is defined by the end result. Interesting...

Comment: Use a non-capturing group, get the same performance: http://jsperf.com/js-repeated-regexp-or-specific-number-of-sequences/2

Comment: @Qtax I'm pretty new to Regular Expressions, that's a excellent piece of info to know. Thanks

Comment: That string doesn't actually contain any end line characters, since escaped newlines are ignored entirely. Furthermore, even tough the first one is slower, it has the benefit of being more readable, and still performs at over a million operations per second.

Comment: @MichaelMorgan Thanks for the input, good points. I updated the JSPerf  and it did in fact change the outcome, but not much. And yeah, the difference between the two is quite small.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in using a capturing group `( )` if you're not going to use the values that are captured.  You can instead use a [non-capturing group](http://javascript.about.com/library/blre16.htm) `(?: )` and get better performance.

So the expression would become:

```
(?:\r?\n){2}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is very little performance difference between the two (the second one is likely a tiny bit slower, but nothing you'd notice in normal situations).

The second expression is better practice, however, because it indicates clearly that the expression consists of a repeating sub-expression.